# Aeson decode JSON object that can be either a string or an int

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm working with some complexly formatted JSON responses from a REST server. To decode them, I have a couple of data types to handle the different nested objects. For example:

```
... Other types ...

data Profile =
  Profile { fields :: [KVPair]
  } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Profile where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    Profile <$> v .: "Fields" 
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data KVPair =
  KVPair { key :: Int
         , value :: String
  } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON KVPair where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    KVPair <$> v .: "Key"
           <*> v .: "Value" 
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Everything works except for the final KVPair type. My JSON objects all have integer keys; however, the values can be either an integer or a string:

```
      {
        "Key": 0,
        "Value": "String Value!"
      },
      {
        "Key": 1,
        "Value": 42
      }
```

Now I suppose I could add another sum type to my value decode that is composed of `String` and `Int`, but I would prefer to avoid adding a whole new type just for that. **Does Aeson have a simple way to handle this scenario?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two simple fixes. One is to simply write

```
data KVPair = KVPair { key :: Int, value :: Value }
```

and leave all other code the same. Consumers will need to check the `Value` to see whether it is a string-y thing or a number-y thing.

Probably the better way is to simply provide two alternative parsers that both convert to your desired format. For example, keeping your `KVPair` definition as is, one might write

```
showInt :: Int -> String
showInt = show

instance FromJSON KVPair where
    parseJSON (Object v)
        =   KVPair
        <$> v .: "Key"
        <*> (v .: "Value" <|> (showInt <$> v .: "Value"))
```

The best of both worlds would be to keep the information about whether it's a `String` or `Int` around *and* to reject other kinds of values; e.g.

```
data KVPair = KVPair { key :: Int, value :: Either String Int }

instance FromJSON KVPair where
    parseJSON (Object v)
        =   KVPair
        <$> v .: "Key"
        <*> (   (Left  <$> v .: "Value")
            <|> (Right <$> v .: "Value")
            )
```

Comment: If I understand your alternative parse method correctly, it would just coerce the integer values to a string type right? So "Value":3 would translate to something like KVPair {value = "3"} right?

Comment: @jkeuhlen Exactly right, though "coerce" has a specific meaning in Haskell that doesn't apply here -- "convert" or "pretty-print" would be closer to correct.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to use the Aeson Value type to work with an Object with fields that can be any JSON value.

Comment: An Object is already a HashMap (in Aeson). Just lookup the Value you need.  If that's not enough you could parse the JSON into an Either String Int